# php redirect page issue

Tags: php, mysql

i used php script to login my application. but it dosen't work well. i want to fix this error. it loads same page. i want to show if username and email is okay then show index page.i use php code in same login view

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $db = new Database();
    $db->query('select email, password from user where email = :email and password = :password');
    $db->bind(':email', $email);
    $db->bind(':password', $pass);
    $db->resultset();
    print_r($db->resultset());

    if($db->rowCount() == 1){

        header('location: index.php');  
    }

}   
?>
```

and this is my login form in same file

```
<form method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">

              <div class="form-group">
                  <h2 style="font-size: 25px; text-align: center; font-weight: 600; margin-bottom: 30px;">LOGIN HERE</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">                  
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="email">Email: </label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required="require" placeholder="Enter email">   
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="password">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required="require" placeholder="Enter password">  
              </div>           

              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Login"/>
      </form>
```

Comment: on your form you should actually call the php file... so action="MY FILE NAME.php" (if both files are on same directory)

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: i code these php and html in same file. how to call

Comment: @GerasimosRagavanis or action="#"

Comment: http error 500 in my cpanel

Comment: Used action name like this action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"

Comment: Where did you put your PHP script? It should be in top place.Have you checked that  what $db->rowCount() is returned ?

Comment: @GerasimosRagavanis I don't know if he even tried it yet or his php code is standing wrong

Comment: it would be great if you accepted one of the answers

Comment: User passwords should ***NEVER*** be stored in plain text form. They should ***ALWAYS*** be only stored in hashed form. Have a read of http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php for info on PHP's functions for dealing with the hashing of passwords and verifying hashed passwords

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line

```
<form method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">
```

with

```
<form method="post" action="#" class="form-horizontal">
```

or

```
<form method="post" action="yourfilename.php" class="form-horizontal">
```

or

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" class="form-horizontal">
```

Comment: i used this but it dosen't working. i'm working with cpanel. so it shows me HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: this redirct to my domian_name/file_name/login.php

Answer (score 0):

**First**, that Code would Only run If you Login Details are Found Correct And Matched a Row in a Database

**Second**, Kindly Update this Code

`'select email, password from user where email = :email and password = :password'`

to

`"SELECT email, password FROM user WHERE email = '$email' and password = '$password'"`

**Lastly**, `header('Location: index.php');`

I Hope this works...

Here you go...

```
<?php  
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Connection Query
    $db = new Database();
    // Fetch Login Data
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    // Login Query
    $login = "SELECT email, password FROM user WHERE email='$email' and password='$pass'";
    // Query SQL
    $req = mysqli_query($db, $login);
    // Check if Row matched is Above Zero
    if (mysqli_num_rows($req) > 0) {
        // Redirect User
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: add an else statement to `if ($db->rowCount() == 1) {
        header('location: index.php');  
    } else { header('location: index.php?msg=failed'); }` try it again and if you see the failed message know it's not your redirecting? but your query script

Comment: i include this else code but it shows http error 500

Comment: Are this the only code on that page? or there are hidden codes we don't know of?

Comment: do you mind if I rewrite your login script for you to use?

Comment: it's okay to rewrite